# Parsing Gmail into Google Sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am trying to parse Gmail with a specific subject and have the data output to a google sheet in specific columns. I had the script working using just the getPlainBody() option, but then I tried to add getDate() and now I am getting an error.

I am sure there is something wrong in my syntax and am now trying various things in the getGmail and gather functions. My current code is below and when ran, the date of the email lands in column A, the entire body of the email lands in column B and I get the error "TypeError: message.replace is not a function".

```
    function onOpen() {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let menuItems = [
        {name: 'Gather emails', functionName: 'gather'},
    ];
    spreadsheet.addMenu('New Employees', menuItems);
}
function gather() {
  let messages = getGmail();
  if (messages.length > 0) {
    let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    curSheet.getRange(curSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, messages.length, messages[0].length).setValues(messages);
     messages.forEach(message => {curSheet.appendRow(parseEmail(message))});
  }
}

function getGmail() {
  const query = "from:(ApplicationServices@help.net) subject:New Account Newer_than:18d NOT label:done";
  let threads = GmailApp.search(query,0,10);

  let label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("done");
  if (!label) {label = GmailApp.createLabel("done")}

  let messages = [];
  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const m = thread.getMessages()[0];
    messages.push([m.getDate(), m.getPlainBody()]);
    label.addToThread(thread);
  });
  return messages;
}

function parseEmail(message){
    let parsed = message.replace(/,/g,'')
        .replace(/\n\s*.+: /g,',')
        .replace(/^,/,'')
        .replace(/\n/g,'')
        .replace(/^[\s]+|[\s]+$/g,'')
        .replace(/\r/g,'')
        .split(',');
    let result = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(index => parsed[index]);

    return result;
}
```

Here is what the emails look like:

> An account has been created:
>
> Employee ID: 987333
> First: Bill
> Last: Walsh
> Username: bwalsh
> Pwd: 67&&8^.!
>
> Employees must change their email password as soon as possible.
> Passwords expire every 90 days and must be 8 characters or more (with
> at least one uppercase, one lowercase and a number or symbol). Note:
> This password is also the password to access Google Email.
>
> If you require assistance please contact your district technical
> support team or the HELP IT Help Desk at 998-9999 or via e-mail at
> helpdesk@help.net.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your `getGmail()` function returns a 2D array where the first value in each subarray is a Date and the second value is a text string. To access the text string, you need to refer to it through index `1`, like this:

```
   messages.forEach(message => { curSheet.appendRow(parseEmail(message[1])) });
```

But it would probably make more sense to remove the above line altogether and run the parse function within `getGmail()`, like this:

```
    messages.push([m.getDate(), parseEmail(m.getPlainBody())]);
```

Comment: Ok - the error is gone, but now - the emails are entered into the sheet twice. The first time it enters the date in column A and then the rest of the body in column B. The second time it enters the data, it parses the email into each column properly - except in column A there is no date, but the text from the beginning of the email "An account has been created:". Any ideas?